# How to upload "empty" attributes to PostgreSQL database with python?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I have a .dat file which looks like this:

```
1*100*100*
2*100*200*
3*100*100*
4**100*
5*100*200*
6***
7*100**
8*150*100*
```

I would like to upload the contents of this file to a PostgreSQL database, which looks like this:

```
id   | attr1 | attr2
--------------------
int  | int   | int
```

Everything works fine with the following pyhton script if there is no "empty" record in the original file. But when there is one, it gives me an error message.

Note that the structure of the original file is always stays the same. The number of delimiter characters (* in this case) are always the same, regardless of the emtpy attributes.

I used the following code, and as I mentioned, it's working fine when there are no empty attributes.

```
import csv
import psycopg2

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = 'myuser', host = 'localhost',
    port = "5432", database = 'mydatabase')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with open('c:\\some_dir\\my_filedat','r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='*'):
            query = '''
            insert into my_schema.my_table (id, attr1, attr2)
            values ({},{},{});
            '''.format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
            cursor.execute(query)
            connection.commit()

except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)

finally: 
    if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

The error message I got:
*Error while connecting to PostgreSQL syntax error at or near ","
LINE 4:                     values (4,,100);*

Now I know I could investigate the values of each attributes in every iteration, and if it's '' then I could assign '0' to it, but in reality there are at least 20 attributes and hunderds of thousands of rows, which would make it very time consuming and inefficient.

Also I could convert the .dat files to .csv and upload it using ogr2ogr, but at the end I will only need certain parts of the file, which I'm intended to filter in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the wrong approach. Use bind values instead of Python string formatting.

Instead of

```
query = '''
insert into my_schema.my_table (id, attr1, attr2)
values ({},{},{});
'''.format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
cursor.execute(query)
```

Try this

```
query = '''
insert into my_schema.my_table (id, attr1, attr2)
values (%s, %s, %s)
'''
cursor.execute(query, (int(row[0]), int(row[1]), int(row[2])))
```

Comment: @588chm By the way - you are at risk of SQL injection with your original code. Use bind values whenever possible. If you can't bind a variable and must format it into the dynamic query, then make sure that the role connecting to the DB follows the least privileges principle.

Answer (score 0):

No way around it. You need to ensure that if you encounter a blank value in the data file, you substitute `null` so that the generated values list looks like `values (4,null,100)` instead of `values (4,,100)`

So, I guess you'd do something like

```py
. . .
'''.format(row[0] or "null", row[1] or "null", row[2] or "null")
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working, but only if the type of the column is _character varying_.

Comment: Using string formatting to pass variables to SQL queries is error prone and can lead to SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

I've found a not so great, but working solution. If I change the type of the columns in PostgreSQL to character varying, I can use the folowwing modifications. I've put the {}-s between aposthropes. After uploading, I can cast the columns to integer. Not so convinient but it's working.

```
query = '''
insert into my_schema.my_table (id, attr1, attr2)
values ('{}','{}','{}');
'''.format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

Comment: Using string formatting to pass variables to SQL queries is error prone and can lead to SQL injection. – Ilja Everilä just now